# How to save the state of two toggle buttons?

Tags: android

I am making a project in which i am using two toggle buttons and i have to save there state so that it can work in background as per it is saved or not.
I am able to save the state of first togglebutton but not able to save the state of second togglebutton and the second one can also start and stop service as per
. So can anyone tell what must i do so that i can save the state of togglebuttons

Code...

```
<ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/tgbattery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:checked="true"
     />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="113dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
        android:checked="true" />


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener{

    ToggleButton tb,tb1;
    SharedPreferences shpref,shpref1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tb = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
        tb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        shpref=getSharedPreferences("announcepref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        tb.setChecked(shpref.getBoolean("is announcer enable", true));
        tb1 = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tgbattery);
        tb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        shpref1=getSharedPreferences("batterypref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        tb1.setChecked(shpref1.getBoolean("is battery enable", true));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BatteryService.class);
        if(tb.isChecked()){
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=shpref.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("is announcer enable", true);
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Call Announcer Activated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }else if(!tb.isChecked()){
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=shpref.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("is announcer enable", false);
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Call Announcer Deactivated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(tb1.isChecked()){
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=shpref1.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("is battery enable", true);
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Low Battery Alert Activated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startService(i);
        }
        else if(!tb1.isChecked()){
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=shpref1.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("is battery enable", false);
            editor.commit();
            stopService(i);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Low Battery Alert Deactivated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you check that tb1 is checked or not like this :

```
if(tb1.isChecked()){
//Then start your service.
}
```

after you check with which toggle is pressed after check that toggle values like this :

```
@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BatteryService.class);
        if(arg0.equals(tb))
        {
            if(tb.isChecked()){
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=shpref.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("is announcer enable", true);
                editor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Call Announcer Activated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else if(!tb.isChecked()){
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=shpref.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("is announcer enable", false);
                editor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Call Announcer Deactivated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }   
        }
        else if (arg0.equals(tab1))
        {
            if(tb1.isChecked()){
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=shpref1.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("is battery enable", true);
                editor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Low Battery Alert Activated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startService(i);
            }
            else if(!tb1.isChecked()){
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=shpref1.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("is battery enable", false);
                editor.commit();
                stopService(i);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Low Battery Alert Deactivated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: its working but i want in the starting it must check if tb1 is on it must start the service –  Abhi 42 secs ago

Comment: i want to give a button on incoming call screen can anyone tell please how may i do that??

Comment: are you give this toggle on call screen?

Comment: no its separate i dont want to give this toggle on call screen but i want to give a simple button on call screen can you please tell how can i do that??

Comment: what r u trying to say?

Comment: i want to setup a simple button on incoming call screen...so that when i click over that button i can perform some specific action over that

Comment: device native incoming call screen?

Comment: so can i setup a image?

Comment: or can i give up a popup image or button or a small message so that i can stop the caller announcer on clicking that image

Answer (score 1):

In onCheckedChanged() the last 2 **else if** tests will never be executed, because either tb.isChecked() will be true or !tb.isChecked() will be true.

Try simplifying and fixing it this way:

```
    if (arg0.equals(tb)) {
        if (tb.isChecked()){
            final SharedPreferences.Editor editor=shpref.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("is announcer enable", true);
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Call Announcer Activated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            final SharedPreferences.Editor editor=shpref.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("is announcer enable", false);
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Call Announcer Deactivated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else if (arg0.equals(tb1)) {
        if (tb1.isChecked()) {
            final SharedPreferences.Editor editor=shpref1.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("is battery enable", true);
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Low Battery Alert Activated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            final SharedPreferences.Editor editor=shpref1.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("is battery enable", false);
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Low Battery Alert Deactivated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    if (tb1.isChecked()) {
        startService(i);
    } else {
        stopService(i);
    }
```

Comment: yes i got this may i know how could i check the second toggle and start service as per that

Comment: Try changing the third test from 'else if ' to just 'if'. See my edited answer.

Comment: its working but i want in the starting it must check if tb1 is on it must start the service

Comment: I borrowed the arg0 tests from @HarshitRathi's answer, and separated out the start/stop service calls so that either starting or stopping the service will always be done. Starting a started service or stopping a stopped service should do no harm, according to the Android specs.